# javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element

Tags: java, xml, wsdl, websphere

I'm having the follow issue, but I don't find a solution and it doesn't makes sense:

```
[javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element
 (uri:"http://facade.filenet.bradesco.com.br", local:"criarDocumentoIdResponse").
 Expected elements are
  <{}adicionarDocumentoFolder>,<{}adicionarDocumentoFolderResponse>,
  <{}alterarClasseIcor>,<{}alterarClasseIcorPermissao>,
  <{}alterarClasseIcorPermissaoResponse>,<{}alterarClasseIcor]Response>,
  <{}alterarClasseNome>,<{}alterarClasseNomePermissao>,
  <{}alterarClasseNomePermissaoResponse>,<{}alterarClasseNomeResponse>,
  <{}consultarDocumentosSearchTemplate>,<{}consultarDocumentosSearchTemplateResponse>,
  <{}consultarDocumentosStoredSearch>,<{}consultarDocumentosStoredSearchResponse>,
  <{}criarDocumento>,<{}criarDocumentoId>,
  <{}criarDocumentoIdResponse>,
  <{}criarDocumentoResponse>,<{}obterChoiceList>,
  <{}obterChoiceListResponse>,<{}obterConteudoDocumento>,
  <{}obterConteudoDocumentoResponse>,<{}obterValorItemChoiceList>,
  <{}obterValorItemChoiceListResponse>,<{}removerDocumentoCentroCusto>,
  <{}removerDocumentoCentroCustoResponse>,<{}removerDocumentoFolder>,
  <{}removerDocumentoFolderResponse>
```

The `criarDocumentoIdResponse` can be found in the expected elements.

Comment: I believe the element in the document has an `xmlns` of http://facade...`, but the `{}` mean the expected elements do not have a namespace.  If you post the XML, it should be easy to fix it, but I don't know if that is the "right" fix, or if your webservice should be defined differently to accept your current input.

Comment: Can you check the namespace is same in both @XmlRootElement(name=""  namespace="") and XSD.